# What does $\rm kg m^{-2}$ mean in simple terms?

Tags: dimensional-analysis, density, si-units

I'm reading a research paper on fish stocking density and they measure the density in terms of  $\rm kg m^{-2}$ (i.e. stocking density is 1.27  $\rm kg m^{-2}$). I've googled it but still don't have a good grasp on what a kg m is. Is kg m just an alternate way of writing kg/m or does it mean something else? How does the -2 exponent factor in?

Comment: Negative powers (i.e. x^(-y)) are just another way to write 1 / (x^y).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a question about physics

Comment: @JohnRennie how is the meaning of units notation not physics?

Comment: @Ruslan everything is measured in some units. That doesn't mean everything is physics.

Comment: @JohnRennie I mean I just classed it under physics because it had to do with density, which as far as I'm aware is a physics concept, sorry if it clogged your feed or something

Answer (score 7):

This is the mass of fish (kg) per surface area of lake (inverse square meters, or $\mathrm m^{-2}$), aka: areal density.

Answer (score 2):

You can think of negative exponents as fractions, for example

$$
  x^{-3}=1/x^3
$$

Then, in your case  $kgm^{-2}$ express a ratio $kg/m^{2}$ , that would mean amount of kilograms of fish per meter squared, which is the common unit for denoting area.

Answer (score 0):

it is density of kg per unit area.
m^-2= 1/m^2

aka kg/m^2